# Multiple condition check and filter between multiple dataframes

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have two dataframes and am trying to use one dataframe as the filtering df and the other is the one being filtered. Here is how the two dataframes look like:

```
df #(filtering)
   phrase1   date1
0  cat       2012-03-04    
1  tree      2015-05-02    
2  snail     2002-08-27 
3  dog       2004-02-27 

df1 #(being filtered)
   id       phrase2        date2
0  abc12    cat nip        2003-03-04  
1  def34    baobab tree    2009-05-02    
2  ghi56    lazy dog       2011-08-27 
3  jkl78    poor snail     2014-08-27 
4  mno90    fat cat        2008-08-27
```

I'm trying to implement some logic where:

- if any of the strings in the `phase1` column of dataframe `df` match any of the strings in the `phase2` column of dataframe `df1`, **AND** if `date1` in dataframe `df` *precedes* `date2` in dataframe `df1`:

  -- **drop** the word that matched in `df1['phrase2']`
- if any of the strings in the `phase1` column of dataframe `df` match any of the strings in the `phase2` column of dataframe `df1`, **AND** if `date1` in dataframe `df` *comes after* `date2` in dataframe `df1`:

  -- **keep** the word that matched in `df1['phrase2']`

I can't figure out how to do this though. I've tried fiddling around with `np.where` and joining two conditions with the & operator (eg. `np.where((condition1)&(condition2),'something','somethingelse'`), but it keeps throwing me off with the complexity. Please help..

Expected outcome:

```
df1 
   id       phrase2        date2
0  abc12    cat nip        2003-03-04  
1  def34    baobab tree    2009-05-02 
2  ghi56    lazy           2011-08-27  
3  jkl78    poor           2014-08-27   
4  mno90    fat cat        2008-08-27 
#occurrences of dog and snail are gone because date1 dates came before date2 dates 
#for those particular words.
```

Comment: Waht is expected output - how looks DataFrame?

Comment: added edits to include expected outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#create dict for map if one word phrase
d = df.set_index('phrase1')['date1'].to_dict()

#if splitted strings like in original df
#d = {c: b for a, b in zip(df['phrase1'], df['date1']) for c in a.split()}
#print (d)

#join togther for list of tuples
zipped = zip(df1['phrase2'], df1['date2'])
#max Timestamp contant
mt = pd.Timestamp.max
#nested list comprehension with filtering
a = [' '.join([y for y in a.split() if not (d.get(y, mt) < b and y in d)]) for a, b in zipped]
print (a)
['cat nip', 'baobab tree', 'lazy', 'poor', 'fat cat']

df1['phrase2'] = a
print (df1)
      id      phrase2      date2
0  abc12      cat nip 2003-03-04
1  def34  baobab tree 2009-05-02
2  ghi56         lazy 2011-08-27
3  jkl78         poor 2014-08-27
4  mno90      fat cat 2008-08-27
```